# why is Keras accuracy metrics not measuring the same as the sklearn.metrics accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning, data-science

I  have a model with this compilation:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

When i fit the model and call this:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=10, epochs=10) 
score_user = model.evaluate(X_test,y_test)
```

it gives me 0.13 of accuracy, but with this:

```
pred = model.predict(X_test)
pred = pred.round(0)
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
score_user = accuracy_score(y_test,pred)
```

it gives me almost 0.5 of score.

y_test is an 2D array with 0 and 1(each instance has almost 2000 classes to be predicted) with 0 and 1, like:

```
[[0,1,0,0,0....,1],[0,1,0,0,0....,1],[0,1,0,0,0....,1],[0,1,0,0,0....,1]]
```

I tested acuracy_score from sklearn, and i know that it returns the proportion of the rows of pred that is exactly the same as y_test. So, what is Keras accuracy metrics measuring???

Comment: Based on the loss function you are using, this is a binary classification task. I would expect `y_test` to be a 1-dimensional array. Why is your `y_test` multi-dimensional and what would expect accuracy to mean in this case?

Comment: It's for predicting what products would a customer give rating of 5 star. I'm using almost 2000 products. 1 is when he would rate, 0 is he wouldn't

Comment: each of the neurons from the last layer represents one product

Comment: For the test that i made in sklearn accuracy score, the accuracy was meaning the proportion of the customer that gave 5 stars in all products the model predicted to him.

Comment: Just to check: you are sure that the 0.13 is the accuracy, not e.g. the loss?

Comment: yes, 0.13 was the accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you probably want to flatten `y_test` and `y_pred` into 1D arrays and measure accuracy. This would give you a measure of how well the model can identify if a given customer would "like" a given product.

You can also treat this as a binary recommender system problem- your model has to recommend to a user only the products they would like. Then you can use standard recommendation metrics like mean average precision, mean reciprocal rank, etc (I don't think these are available in sklearn)

Comment: The comparison of the two arrays flatten was the other metric i was using. 
What i'm trying to understand is why keras accuracy metric in the evaluate method isn't equal to sklearn accuracy metric

Comment: Because accuracy is usually defined on 1D arrays, and you are using 2D. There's no obvious right answer here, and it just so happens that sklearn and keras' correct implementations for 1D do not crash and produce some output for 2D. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ddca4b92b4eb4e187716b03f443362c904bdad7e/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py  and https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2b503bdc08615ab64e91576d91794e126850abbb/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py#L126